# Change navigation bar color, Android

Tags: java, android, xml

How can I change the color/transparency of the Navigation Bar from black to a generic color in pre-Lollipop devices (e.g. the color of the status bar or of the action bar)?

Can I do it using AppCompat or is it only possible for SDK 21?

Comment: Check this [link](https://x.appgyver.com/categories/3-user-interface-and-design/contents/16-customizing-navigation-bar-appearance)

Comment: This (http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/navigation_bar/Images/19_-_NavBar.png
) is the navigation bar I meant.

Answer (score 10):

You can set the attribute `navigationBarColor` in an AppCompat theme, or `android:navigationBarColor` in a native v21 theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    ...
    <item name="navigationBarColor">#123456</item>
</style>
```

https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#StatusBar

Note that this does not work on Pre-Lollipop devices, since this feature needs to be supported by the system, which is not the case on Android 4.4 or older.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for something that works for pre-Lollipop devices also (minSDK 11).

Comment: That's not possible afaik

Comment: Is it at least possible for Lollipop devices using appcompat so that I don't have to set the minSDK to 21?

Comment: I get `No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'navigationBarColor'.`

Comment: there is not `navigationBarColor` for appCompat You have to use the native v21 `android:navigationBarColor` in values-21

Answer (score 5):

Another programmatically way:

```
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.DarkOrange));
window.setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

Further, to change your status bar color, add the following line:

```
window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS); was the thing I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

style-v21

```
<resources>

<style name="Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Base.Theme.DesignDemo">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>//translucent
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```