# Changing the navigation bar color programmatically on LG Q6

Tags: android, navigationbar

I try to change the color of the navigation bar, either via a theme, or programmatically.

Here is what I tried so far:

in style-v21:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#123456</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#012345</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#987654</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

programmatically:

```
Window w = getWindow();
w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
w.setNavigationBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));
```

The problem is: it works perfectly on Nexus devices (with Android 7.1.1), **but not on a LG Q6** (also with Android 7.1.1).

I think there is a way to do it (since the Youtube app has its own navigation bar color), but I don't know how.

I also tried pretty much everything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27348336/how-to-change-system-navigation-bar-color), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303597/android-change-navigation-bar-color), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47960026/how-change-navigation-bar-color), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839105/android-lollipop-change-navigation-bar-color) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27589833/change-navigation-bar-color-android/33595625), with no success.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Running into this as well, all devices we've tested default to a black navigation bar, except for my LG V20 which displays a light navigation bar. Everything I've tried so far hasn't changed the navigation bar color on my V20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
<application>
....
<meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.5" />
...
</application>
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Looks like without this tag declared, some vendors disable some features, because   you not guarantee wide-screen support. It's my guess though, I found it in experimental way.